# is it possible to use global variables in values.yaml of inner helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, charts, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I have two helm charts, the second one is nested to the first
tree output:

```
.
└── outerChart
    ├── charts
    │   └── innerChart
    │       ├── charts
    │       ├── Chart.yaml
    │       ├── templates
    │       │   ├── deployment.yaml
    │       │   ├── _helpers.tpl
    │       │   ├── ingress.yaml
    │       │   ├── NOTES.txt
    │       │   ├── serviceaccount.yaml
    │       │   └── service.yaml
    │       └── values.yaml
    ├── Chart.yaml
    ├── templates
    └── values.yaml
```

I have a global variable in the outer `values.yaml`:

```
global:
 myreplicacount: 4
```

In the nested chart there is a values file with

```
replicaCount: 1
```

and a deployment that uses it:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "foo.fullname" . }}
  labels:
{{ include "foo.labels" . | indent 4 }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
```

The straight forward way in order to use the global var is to replace:

```
replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
```

with:

```
replicas: {{ .Values.global.myreplicacount }}
```

in the `deployment.yaml`.

But it possible to use that in the nested `values.yaml`? I would like to keep the inner chart intact. I am stuck in a situation where one software team provides me the inner chart and another one provides needed configuration through global variables. `replicaCount` is just an example, they have many variables that need to change and if I edit the inner chart that will make inner chart updates difficult.

Just adding:

```
replicaCount: {{ .Values.global.myreplicacount }}
```

in outerChart/charts/innerChart/values.yaml
returns

```
): error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{".Values.global.myreplicacount":interface {}(nil)}
```

Comment: Could you please share a current tree directory (by running `tree` command) in the main directory where you have the helm charts and tag the files that you mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 2):

Inside the nested chart, `.Values` is seen as the contents of `.Values.nested` (using whatever name for the dependency is in `requirements.yaml` or `Chart.yaml`), merged with the top-level `global:` key.

```yaml
# requirements.yaml
- name: nested   # <-- this name will be used in values.yaml
  version: "^1"
  repository: ...
```

You can provide specific settings for that dependency using its name as a key in `values.yaml`.  This doesn't require `global:` or any changes to the dependency chart.

```yaml
# outer chart values.yaml, or `helm install -f` YAML file
nested:          # <-- matches name: in requirements.yaml above
  replicaCount: 1
```

For a Deployment replica count in particular, I'd prefer this option over possible alternatives.  It's likely that each Deployment and StatefulSet will need a different replica count, especially across multiple charts, and it doesn't make sense to globally say "absolutely everything will have exactly 4 replicas".

If you can edit the nested chart, and you want it to optionally accept a `global:` value, you could honor that if a local value isn't set

```yaml
# charts/nested/deployment.yaml
replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount | default .Values.global.replicaCount | default 1 }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of this option and this is the cleanest but I am stuck in a situation where one software team provides me the inner chart and another one provides needed configuration through global variables. replicaCount is just an example they have many variables that need to change and if I edit the inner chart that will make inner chart updates difficult .

Answer (score 1):

Generally what you want to achieve is not really supported.
However, I'm thinking about simple workaround that may help you.

Before running `helm install` command or whatever you using you can replace values in the nested `values.yaml` from the outer `values.yaml`  by using [`yq` utility](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) (assuming you are in the same directory as from where you ran `tree` command):

```
yq e -i ".replicaCount = $(yq e '.global.myreplicacount' ./outerChart/values.yaml)" ./outerChart/charts/innerChart/values.yaml
```

We are setting the `replicaCount` value in the inner `values.yaml` to the value set in `global.myreplicacount` from the outer `values.yaml` only by using `yq` utility, you don't have to edit manually.

You can insert multiple `yq` commands in the script and just run it before every helm deployment so you will have values in nested `values.yaml` always up-to-date.